# Kindle PaperWhite Page turn glitches

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

I just got my new Kindle PaperWhite (Wifi). Every time I turn the page I see the screen glitch (some thing like blur) for fraction second irrespective whether the page has image or not. Is this in all the devices or could it be a factory defect? Or is there any settings to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [User's guide](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201307530):

> ## Understanding Kindle display technology
>
> Your Kindle uses a high-resolution display technology called electronic paper. The
>   display is  reflective, which means you can read it clearly even in
>   bright sunlight. Electronic paper uses  ink just like books and
>   newspapers, but it displays the ink particles electronically.
>
> On occasion, your screen may seem to flash. This is part of the
>   process of updating the  e-reader display. By default, your Kindle
>   features fast, smooth page turns, minimizing the  number of flashes.
>   To refresh the page with every page turn, from the Home screen tap the
>   Menu button and select Settings. Tap Reading Options and use the Page
>   Refresh setting to  set your preference. For manga refresh settings,
>   tap the Menu button when reading a manga  book and select the Page
>   Refresh On/Off setting.

So, I guess it's common for all devices. My Paperwhite 2 has it too.